# Isopropanol in contact lens solution plastic bottle

Tags: safety, stability, solvents

I have a rather large plastic bottle of isopropanol ($99.7\%$), and I wanted to store some of it in a smaller, more handy container. I have two empty plastic bottles from contact lens solution that I wanted to use, but I'm not sure if it is safe for storing them in there for longer periods of time.

One of them has a 01 symbol inside a triangle, from which I concluded that this means PET and it also has a number 3 inside a circle (I'm not sure what that means).

The other one is HDPE (2 in a triangle) and has a number 5 elsewhere. Are both of those safe for long term storage of isopropanol?

I do intend to mark them very clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like you've determined both plastics correctly. In general, they both would work fine for storing isopropanol; however, according to the [Thermo Fisher's Labware Chemical Resistance Table](https://tools.thermofisher.com/content/sfs/brochures/D20480.pdf), HDPE is preferred:

#### $\ce{i-PrOH}$ – PET

- $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$: **E** Little or no damage after 30 days of constant exposure;
- $\pu{50 ^\circ C}$: **N** Immediate damage may occur. Not recommended for continuous use.

#### $\ce{i-PrOH}$ – HDPE

- $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$: **E** Little or no damage after 30 days of constant exposure;
- $\pu{50 ^\circ C}$: **E** Little or no damage after 30 days of constant exposure.